# Invalid joystick when I run ros in a virtual machine

Tags: ros, joystick, virtualbox

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to run my ros node inside a virtual machine domU on Xen.

I have pass the USB device to the virtual machine domU. In other words, inside the virtual machine domU, I can see the device /dev/input/js0.

However, when I launch the ros node which needs to access the joystick. It reports the error:
Unknown joystick (2 axes, 3 buttons)
Invalid joystick.

The joystick I'm using is joystick used for Xbox360. If I use lsusb command, it shows Xbox360 Controller.

I don't have this issue if I run my ros node on the physical machine.

My question is:
How should I tackle this issue?  The error suggest the emulated usb device seen by the virtual machine is incorrect. But how can I find out which part of the joystick device is incorrect? How should I narrow down the problem?

Thank you very much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/164821/invalid-joystick-when-i-run-ros-in-a-virtual-machine/) by [pennpanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/10191/pennpanda/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-05-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Probably a special case, but maybe by random chance you experience the same issue: The USB dongle of the wireless mouse I use appears as a joystick device in Ubuntu and takes the `/dev/input/js0` slot by default. If I connect a joystick, it automatically gets mapped to `/dev/input/js1` by default. So you might want to check if you have multiple joystick devices on your system.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [pennpanda](https://answers.ros.org/users/10191/pennpanda/) on 2014-05-15**:
Thank you very much, Stefan! Yes! That's the issue. After I change to js3, which is the Xbox360 joystick, I can use it now! :)

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You may need to add permission to your usb port :

```
$> chmod o+rwx /dev/ttyUSB0
```

---

Originally posted by [ROSkinect](https://answers.ros.org/users/17876/roskinect/) with karma: 751 on 2014-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1